# Вывод списка маркеров в зоне видимости 2GIS API

Tags: 2gis-api

Есть какой-то способ получить список маркеров из зоны видимости карты? Например приближаю город и получаю список маркеров только того что есть в текущей видимости по этому городу.

Comment: конкретно с 2GIS не работал, но в других сервисах подобные вещи решались так: находились координаты границы видимости слева, справа, сверху, снизу. После чего производился поиск по координатам `A1 < ШИРОТА < A2`, `B1 < ДОЛГОТА < B2`

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо большое!